# ASP.NET 2.0 - scaffolding a database table for webforms

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, webforms, scaffolding

Can you recommend a tool that can analyze a SQL database table, read the table columns, and populate an .aspx page with appropriate controls (i.e. textboxes with matching labels)?

See this [demo of ComponentOne InputPanel](http://www.componentone.com/newimages/Products/Videos/StudioEnterprise/InputPanel/ComponentOneInputPanel.html) for WinForms for the functionality desired.

Are there any built-in tools for ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms that can help build a scaffold page for any given database table or entity?
Are there any free components out there to help achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/DynamicData/) page for this?

Here's a [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-433.aspx) video. It focuses on using VS 2008.

If you can't directly use the output of Dynamic Data due to a v2.0 limitation, you could perhaps fire up a new DD project in 3.5, and have the scaffold built for you. Then **copy-paste the resultant markup**, and paste into your 2.0 page. That would get you a head-start on not having to create all those `asp:textbox` and `asp:dropdownlist` controls yourself. You'd then have to wire up the DataSources as you see fit.

Comment: I know I can use a FormView but let's say my table has 50 columns, I have to add 50 textboxes and then add data binding to the 50 textboxes matching them up with the columns.

With the tool I am searching for, I would be able to click once and add 50 textboxes, already databound to the matching columns.

Comment: @Francis - Dynamic Data allows just that.

Comment: I see, sorry I missed it before. Dynamic Data looks great, unfortunately we are on .net 2.0 and it looks like Dynamic Data is available for .net 3.5SP1.

Comment: I decided to try out Dynamic Data - can you clarify this part: "copy-paste the resultant markup". Do you mean the HTML source code that's generated? I'm trying to make the Dynamic Data framework generate an aspx page that I can then edit. For example, move around the controls, add additional labels, change controls to radio button or dropdown if necessary, add child grids.